# Не удается подключиться к серверу mysql 5.7 по локальной сети

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Есть локальная сеть в ней 2 компа и я подключаюсь средствами jdbc к бд которая находится на втором компе не на том с которого я выполняю код но видает ошибку подскажите пожалуйста что делать?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.105.101:3306/world", "root", "1997");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'DESKTOP-3BV9' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: А адрес доступен с этого компьютера? Можете подключиться к нему через Workbench, например?

Comment: А как ето проверить через workbench не подключаеться

Comment: Попробуйте в google по этой ошибке посмотреть. Там что-то с правами доступа по этому ip для этого user.

Comment: В MySQL 5.7 и новее по умолчанию учетная запись `root` использует метод авторизации через плагин и предназначена для локального использования. Чтобы оно пускало root по сети, вроде бы, нужно изменить на тип авторизации по паролю и добавить для root-а сетевой адрес (там по-умолчанию стоит localhost). Или просто нужно создать другого пользователя с правами доступа по сети, которому разрешено все то же, что и root'у. И еще одна возможная проблема: а Вы в настройках MySQL разрешали ей работать по сети? По-умолчанию, сервер работает только с `localhost`.

Comment: Как изменить ети настройки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если быть кратким... При настройке MySQL для работы по сети нужно:

1. разрешить ей слушать внешний интерфейс (есть и более изощренный вариант - с помощью фаервола или других системных средств перенаправлять пакеты с внешнего интерфейса с определенного порта на localhost, а его уже слушает MySQL по умолчанию);
2. создать пользователя/разрешить пользователю работать удаленно.

С первым пунктом однозначно сказать "где" сложно, так как в разных дистрибутивах linux с разными версиями MySQL - это все разные места и файлы. А еще, есть вариант с Windows. Поэтому могу сказать только на примере конкретного Xubuntu 18.04, MySQL 5.7. В указанной системе в файле `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` необходимо найти строку `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` в секции `[mysqld]` и заменить в ней адрес (127.0.0.1) на `0.0.0.0` (если строка bind-address закомментирована - раскомментируйте, если ее нет (а она в описанной системе есть), то можно ее добавить в указанную секцию). Это простейший вариант. Должно получиться в файле как-то так:

```
[mysqld]
...
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Естественно, после этой операции необходимо перезагрузить сервер mysql. 
Например, так:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

В случае, если на Вашей системе нет таких подкаталогов и такого файла, можно искать такую же секцию `[mysqld]` в `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Вроде бы, так было в предыдущих версиях MySQL.

В случае, если у Вас сервер работает под MS Windows, то указанную секцию настройки службы MySQL нужно искать в файле `my.ini` (возможно, он находится в каталоге `MySQL\DATA` - точно не могу указать, у меня нет MySQL под Windows). И здесь, скорее всего, строку `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` нужно будет добавить самому.

---

Со вторым пунктом немного проще. На компьютере с MySQL сервером войдите в системную консоль MySQL с правами администратора. Далее, посмотреть текущий список пользователей и способ доступа Вы можете командой:

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

Получите таблицу, где Вам напишут, что `root` имеет вид авторизации как `auth_socket`, и что он не может пользоваться удаленным сеансом. В принципе, на этом можете и забыть про эту учетную запись `root` (Вы можете создать нового `root`-а с указанием адреса, и это уже будет другой пользователь). Далее, создайте нового пользователя с возможностью сетевого доступа (в имя пользователя входит и сетевой адрес, с которого разрешено проводить сеансы) и наделите его необходимыми привилегиями. Насколько я понимаю, это можно сделать и за одну команду, но мне понятнее, когда каждое действие сделано отдельно.

```
CREATE USER 'юзер'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'невзламываемый_пароль';
```

здесь: `юзер` - имя вашего пользователя (да, можно и кириллицей), `%` - означает, что пользователю разрешено работать с любого сетевого адреса. Вместо него можно написать конкретный адрес, типа `10.0.0.1`. Ну, с паролем, думаю, понятно. Задаете свой.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'юзер'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Эта строка разрешит делать для указанного пользователя (имя и адрес обязательно должны совпадать с тем, что вводили при создании пользователя) всё что можно для всех баз данных и всех таблиц. Если нужно ограничиться какой-то конкретной базой или даже таблицей в базе, то вместо `*.*` нужно указать имя базы и имя таблицы. Если нужно урезать в правах, то вместо `ALL PRIVILEGES` нужно писать список того, что хотите разрешить (чтобы узнать полный список очень рекомендую воспользоваться документацией).

И после всего сделанного нужно выполнить команду

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Она нужна только в том случае, если привилегии меняли отдельно от создания пользователя. Если все делать за одну команду, то тогда, вроде бы, последняя команда не нужна.

В общем, так получился пользователь с правами как у `root`, которому можно работать удаленно. Естественно, для промышленных систем за такое должны надавать по рукам (и остальным подвернувшимся местам), ибо слишком много привилегий на одного пользователя.

Теперь, можно выполнить команду типа:

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;
```

И тогда будет видно, каким пользователям можно работать с БД с каких адресов.

А запрос:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'юзер'@'%';
```

покажет список привилегий указанного пользователя. Вот, как-то так.