# java.sql.sqlexception access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.0.3'

Tags: java, mysql, localhost

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе запущенной из XAMPP с другого компьютера по локалке. Адрес сервера 192.168.0.2, а адрес клиента 192.168.0.3. А самого сервера тот же приложения подключается и работает на ура.
На рут не установил пароль. Пробовал создать новую учетку с паролем все равно ошибка. Насиловал гугл вечность. Никак не могу решить проблему, уже готов сдаться и написать аппликуху на сервере чтобы тот обращался на базу и передал по TCP клиенту. Кто нибудь сталкивался вообще такой литтл проблем?

Comment: Плохо насиловали гугля. Дубликат вопроса [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892527/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-mysql-5-7-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8/893568#893568]

Comment: а порт открыт на том компютере?

Comment: @Михаил Ребров - скорее открыт, потому что мускл отвечает же.

Comment: @Vladimir Не дубликат, прежде чем написать сюда я эти статьи и вопросы уже прошел. Vladimir и потом у парня другая ошибка java.sql.SQLException: null, message from server: "Host 'DESKTOP-3BV9' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server". Создал новый юзер с паролем и привилегиями, конфиги my.ini поправил, все равно не получается. В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: Если эти вопросы уже прошел, тогда стоило упомянуть в вопросе, что то-то и то-то проверял, вот это работает, а вот именно это - нет. Как уже сказали выше, это может быть и ненастроенный фаервол. И неверные политики доступа в Windows (да, почему Вы не написали какие используете системы?). А еще, может оказаться кривой конфиг самой явы. Вы пробовали соединение  другим клиентом? Хоть с тем же MySQL Workbench? Тогда могли бы часть возможных проблем отсеять.